# How to use the L4 Microkernel with a FreeBSD userland

Tags: linux, kernel, freebsd, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm trying to understand how to use the L4 Microkernel with a FreeBSD userland. I've asked the same to a L4 developer,but he told me that he does not know FreeBSD,so I'm here to ask the same question. First of all I'm sure that it can be done,because it is written clearly on their website :

http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/L4Re/download/snapshots/

on the section :

**Host system requirements**

The host system shall be a 64bit-based system with a recent Linux distribution installed and at least 2GB of free disk space.

All necessary tools required by the build are available from the provided packages of the Linux distributions, including cross compilers. But there are also other cross compiler packages available (see below). You might want to run make check_build_tools in the src/l4 directory to verify the common tools are installed.

You are free to use any Linux distribution you like, or even BSDs or any of its derivatives. But then you should know the game. Especially tool versions should be recent, as installed on the listed distributions below.

We are confident that the snapshot works on the following distributions:

```
Debian 11 or later
Ubuntu 22.04 or later
```

Let's say I want to use the L4 microkernel + FreeBSD 14 on my Raspberry Pi 4,the first step I did was to build L4Re for the Rpi,according with this instructions :

http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/L4Re/rpi.html

This is the log file of the compilation,that hasn't given any  error :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/6SwN2mpJBM/

Or I could have taken a pre built image of the L4 microkernel here :

http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/download/snapshots/pre-built-images/arm64/

At this point the tutorial says that I should use a Linux distro. They suggest the official distro for the Raspberry Pi 4,that's RaspBian. But I don't want to use Linux as a userland,I want to use FreeBSD. The question now is : what should I do to achieve that goal ? How can I link the L4 microkernel with the ubldr bootloader of FreeBSD ? Or should I link it to the kernel of FreeBSD ? Can someone explain to me the missing step ? thanks.

Comment: bit surprised the FreeBSD userland would run on L4! `.*`BSDs have the luxury of being able to develop their userland in lockstep with their kernels, so that things might not be as universal. Then again, bsdutils do even work on Linux and Mac OS, so you might be on to something!

Comment: And: that website you link to says *nothing* about what you want being possible? It just says that you can cross-compile a specific L4 kernel for ARM on a x86 host that's Linux or similar enough to Linux. Nothing about the userland running on that target kernel is stated…

Comment: They say : You are free to use any Linux distribution you like, or even BSDs or any of its derivatives....

Comment: As said, *for compiling the kernel*. Not as a userland!

Comment: It does not seem to me. They talked about Linux distribution,then to BSDs. They talk about any BSD "distribution".

Comment: again, the page describes compiling the kernel. Not porting a userland. L4 most definitely does *not* expose a Linux-compatible API.

Comment: you are right. thanks.